# How to find empty lines after a } using bash

Tags: regex, bash, scripting, grep, find

I am trying to use a bash script to identify places in my code that has more than one blank line after a closing `}`

I am able to search and find text using this script:

```
TAGS="text"
find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" \) -print0 | xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "\$match = 1 if s/($TAGS)/ error: \$1/; END { exit \$match; }"
```

But I'm not sure how to search for empty lines that occur after a closing `}` character. Do I need a regex of some sort?

Can someone help me fit these pieces together?

EDIT

To clarify, it would actually be really useful to find only where there was more than one empty line after a }.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one-liner:

```
 awk '/}/{f=1;next} $0 && f{f=0;next} !$0 && f{print "empty line found:"NR}' file
```

let's take an example:

```
kent$  nl -ba file
     1  foo
     2  bar}
     3  
     4  foo2
     5  
     6  
     7  bar2{
     8  
     9  }
    10  
    11  
    12  
    13  eof

kent$  awk '/}/{f=1;next} $0 && f{f=0;next} !$0 && f{print "empty line found:"NR}' file
empty line found:3
empty line found:10
empty line found:11
empty line found:12
```

**EDIT**

dirty and quick for newly updated question:

```
     awk '/}/{f=1;m=0;next} $0 && f{f=0;m=0;next} !$0 && f &&!m{m=1;next} m{print "empty line found:"NR}' file
```

new test:

```
kent$  nl -ba file                                                                                              
     1  foo
     2  bar}
     3  
     4  foo2
     5  
     6  
     7  bar2{
     8  
     9  }
    10  
    11  
    12  
    13  blah{}
    14  
    15  
    16  
    17  
    18  eof

kent$  awk '/}/{f=1;m=0;next} $0 && f{f=0;m=0;next} !$0 && f &&!m{m=1;next} m{print "empty line found:"NR}' file
empty line found:11
empty line found:12
empty line found:15
empty line found:16
empty line found:17
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! I edited my question to add one more detail I didn't realize I was looking for. How could we adjust your answer to show only where there was more than one empty line after the }? Thanks!